# how to optimally store a half million key value pairs?

Tags: python

So, I have an object that has an ID attached to it.  I need to do a lookup on that ID and get a different ID.  I just don’t know the most efficient way to do this.

Essentially, the transformation will look like this:

```
1 -> af567
2 -> at678
3 -> dh675
```

I will be doing this lookup in Python, and all these values are known before runtime.  I thought about Json, SQLite, or a prebuilt dictionary, but I’m just not sure the most optimal route to take.  There will be 500,000 of these pairs stored.  I just need to know the optimal medium to store these pairs

Comment: have you tried anything yet? do you know this is your bottleneck? 500k isn't that many...

Comment: There is a built-in data structure for key-value pairs, you might want to try that.

Comment: my bet would go for a dict

Comment: @Aaron No.  I thought I’d drop a question first before I start attempting this.  I don’t need crazy optimization, like if a lookup takes .1 seconds vs .15 seconds, that’s fine. I’m just concerned if it’s .1 vs 2 seconds or something.

Comment: @Tomalak I just wasn’t sure if using a dictionary was made to be used for so many objects.

Comment: if you start running into memory issues with `dict`, you can play some games with memory mapped arrays or the `struct` library, but 500k isn't that many especially if your keys and values are only a few bytes.. for this purpose a dictionary is going to have constant time lookups, and will be much faster than a database.

Comment: Are the keys always numbers than increase by 1?

Comment: That's a good point that @juanpa is making. If your keys are numbers starting with 1 and simply increasing all the way to 500k, use a list instead of a dict. If your values can somehow be derived from the keys (like in my answer), don't store anything at all and calculate them on demand until you run into performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so you have 500.000 items where a number maps to a five-digit string:

Let's put that to the test

```
def five(i):
    """turns a number into an at least five-digit string"""
    s = hex(s).replace('0x', '')
    return '0' * (5 - len(s)) + s

# 500k items, no duplication
d = {}
for i in range(500000):
    d[i] = five(i)

# see https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/
total_size(d, verbose=False) / 1024 / 1024
# => 33.8720645904541 (megabytes)
```

That's nothing, really. Use a dict.

Comment: To be fair, `getsizeof` only returns the size of the container, and not the objects it contains...

Comment: You are right, I did not think of that. Counted recursively this comes to 35 MB. Still nothing to worry much about. I'll update my answer.

Comment: So, for example, it will account for the pointers to Python string objects, but not the memory of the string objects themselves ( many small strings can require a lot of memory, because they incur the full Python object overhead)

Comment: Thanks! Being able to use a dictionary rather than a db will be much simpler so I’m glad you eased my mind of possible effiency issues

Comment: Try it out on your machine to see if there is any huge difference. Use your real data. Note that I have updated my answer a bit since I originally posted it. Use the linked function to calculate the object size.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga actually, the initial 2 characters on the values are all the same (just realized) so I could essentially have a key value pair where both are ints, and both of the values will be 7 digits max, then append the initial characters to the value int after its retrieved.

Comment: Don't overengineer it. See if that makes an actual difference. Memory is cheap and 500.000 items is not a lot to begin with.